# How to allow certain origin in a crossOriginIsolated page (COEP header)?

Tags: html, browser, cross-domain, cross-origin-opener-policy, ffmpeg-wasm

In order to use `SharedArrayBuffer` that I need for FFmpeg-wasm, I need to enable `cross-origin isolation`. However I cannot load any resources from my CDN. In [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#cross-origin-isolation):

> Once you do this, your page will not be able to load cross-origin content unless the resource explicitly allows it via a Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header or CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-* and so forth).

I tried looking at their documentation on [CORP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) but I cannot find any useful information on how to enable certain origins. My CDN already has `access-control-allow-origin: *` header but seems like it's not the correct header.

What do I need to do to allow `https://cdn.example.com/resource.js` in my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` is **NOT** for my web page, but for the CDN resource (i.e. the server serving the JS file). Adding the header to my **CDN server** solves the problem. For example, `https://cdn.example.com/resource.js` must respond with this header:

```
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
```

Comment: Yes, the header on the host site to allow/disallow cross origin resources is  Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy (COEP)